# Meaning of 祝愿 as wishing or congratulating

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, usage, word, politeness

I wrote 哇，祝愿碰运气，能碰上这个组啊. By this I meant I wish I can be lucky and end up in that group. I am worried it will be taken as congratulations on you being lucky ending up in that group (which sounds like "I think you are just lucky with no ability").

Does it sound like I mean the latter?

Comment: ✓ will be taken as "congratulations"  on (wish for) you ✓ 祝愿；wish so.sth.e.g. (see bkrs)祝愿某人快乐 wish sb. happiness
谨致良好的祝愿 with best wishes
祝愿您健康、 幸福。 I wish you good health and happiness.
祝愿贵国日益繁荣昌盛。 We wish your country evergrowing prosperity.
请接受我最良好的祝愿，祝你幸福和成功。 Please accept my best wishes for your happiness and success.

wish sth. for oneself: **希望、 想要**

Comment: @user6065 Thank you very much for the detailed response. That is not good then, as it means the latter... I'll have to explain to him I meant the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who got in the group? You or I??

哇，祝愿碰运气，能碰上这个组啊

*I wish I can be lucky and end up in that group.

I hope that I will be lucky and end up in that group.

我希望我能有幸加入那个组。

Wow! You are lucky to end up in that group!

哇！你运气真好，加入到了那个组！

If you want to indicate the person's ability got him/her in that group:

You deserve to be in that group, you are very talented.

你非常有天赋，值得在那个组。

Congratulations! = 恭喜你！ 或者 祝贺您！